# Go Unmarshal YAML into struct with maps

Tags: go, yaml

I'm attempting to unmarshal a YAML file into a struct containing two maps (using [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)).

YAML-file:

```
'Include':
    - 'string1'
    - 'string2'

'Exclude':
    - 'string3'
    - 'string4'
```

The struct:

```
type Paths struct {
    Include map[string]struct{}
    Exclude map[string]struct{}
}
```

A simplified version (i.e. removed error handling etc.) of the function attempting to unmarshal:

```
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

func getYamlPaths(filename string) (Paths, error) {
    loadedPaths := Paths{
        Include: make(map[string]struct{}),
        Exclude: make(map[string]struct{}),
    }

    filenameabs, _ := filepath.Abs(filename)
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filenameabs)

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &loadedPaths)
    return loadedPaths, nil
}
```

Data is being read from the file, but the unmarshal-function is not putting anything into the struct, and is returning no errors.

I suspect that the unmarshal-function cannot turn the YAML collections into `map[string]struct{}`, but as mentioned it is producing no errors, and I've looked around for similar issues and can't seem to find any.

Any clues or insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through debugging I found multiple problems. First, `yaml` doesn't seem to care about the fields names. You *have* to annotate the fields with a

```
`yaml:"NAME"`
```

Second, in the YAML file, `Include` and `Exclude` both contain only a list of strings, not something similar to a map. So your struct becomes:

```
type Paths struct {
    Include []string `yaml:"Include"`
    Exclude []string `yaml:"Exclude"`
}
```

And it works. Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var str string = `
'Include':
    - 'string1'
    - 'string2'

'Exclude':
    - 'string3'
    - 'string4'
`

type Paths struct {
    Include []string `yaml:"Include"`
    Exclude []string `yaml:"Exclude"`
}

func main() {
    paths := Paths{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &paths)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", paths)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did attempt using slices as you've suggested here, but i assume that did not work due to the lack of tags in the struct. Until i can come up with something better i guess i'll just turn them into maps after they're loaded in!